# Show that $S^n$ is not contractible in $S^n \times S^n$

Tags: differential-topology

> Show that $\{x\} \times S^n \hookrightarrow S^n \times S^n$ is not contractible

It is correct to say that $\{x\} \times S^n$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n$ then it would be enough to prove that $S^n$ is contractible in $S^n \times S^n$ intuitively I can understand that a copy of $S^n$ embedded in $S^n \times S^n$ cannot be contracted as $S^n \times S^n$ has a hole in it (thinking of e.g. $S^{1} \times S^{1}$ ) so there I will have problems. I am trying to find a contradiction supposing that the embedding $j:S^n \rightarrow S^n \times S^n$ is homotopic to a constant but I have not been successful, I am trying this way because in my course we have not touched homology or homotopy groups, I think that not being able to use these tools increases the difficulty.
for the moment I can only basically use the tools in the first chapter of Guillemin/Pollack's book, Sard's theorem, Whitney's embedding theorem, stability theorem, transversality, etc

Any help or suggestion I will be very grateful

Comment: I have a question, what do you mean by $\pi_n$? 
and about the other, I am currently studying differential topology and in my list of problems I have found this one in particular, I would like to be able to use the homotopy or homology tools but apparently I have to look for other ways.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, for the moment I can only basically use the tools in the first chapter of Pollack's book, Sard's theorem, Whitney's theorem, stability theorem, transversality, etc

Comment: In that case, the only relevant tag is differential topology. No homotopy theory, no algebraic topology, as I was editing. You should edit your post to include those last comments on the tools you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanks @TedShifrin

Comment: Are you sure you can’t go into chapter 2 and use the most basic facts about (mod 2) intersection numbers?